# Что Вы можете сказать о Babel.js (6to5)?

Tags: препроцессор, javascript

Считаю, что js знаю на твердую четверку, и теперь хочу перейти на следующий уровень,
а именно использовать препроцессоры. Смотрел typescript, который мне понравился, но он так же, как и coffee, вымышленный, в отличии от Babel, который совсем недавно назывался 6to5.
Мне хочется использовать его из-за того, что он повторяет будущие версии js, но есть какое-то непонятно сомнение, которое, надеюсь, с Вашей помощью развеять.
Что Вы можете сказать о Babel? Стоит его использовать?

И если модераторам покажется, что вопрос ведет к спору, то не удаляйте его, а скажите лучше, как тему переназвать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не бойтесь, используйте, причин для сомнений нет. ES2015 уже зафиксирован, так что в бой.